# Browser not interactable when debugging JavaScript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

When the debugger hits on the breakpoint in Internet Explorer 11 it is not possible to interact with the website. A large pause icon is displayed above the browser and the website is grayed out, and there is no way to click on anything on the site, which is very necessary to do in this case to be able to find the error. This is possible to do in both firefox and chrome (of course). Any workaround to turn of this or any addons that can be used instead of the built in debugger?

In advance, thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit a breakpoint, code execution stops, which means that your clicks cannot be received. The browser is greyed out to signify that.

Explain your intention, and perhaps we can help you with debugging, although you may need to create a different question on SO to avoid diverging too much.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of this, but hoped someone had a workaround. The problem is a bit complex, so I will find another way of solving it. Thanks for help anyways. Maybe I will create a new question, but will look for other solutions first :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#_break, it will tell you about using breakpoints with F12 Dev Tools, including the fact that

> the browser will not respond to any user input.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no way around this. Each tab only gets a single thread for JS (generally speaking, ignoring web workers, etc.) and when you're debugging the JS thread is paused.

If you need to see what's happening when you press a button you'll need to drop a breakpoint into the code that handles the button press. If you're trying to find the effect of a button press while in the middle of a running function, then good news: this doesn't happen. If you click a button while a function is executing, the button press will be pushed onto the stack and handled after the function execution has completed.